# How do you use the WP REST API to display search results in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a search field that I would like to generate the results of a user's search by pulling data from the JSON files from the WP REST API.  I need to do this in plain javascript and I am working within a javascript class for OOP. Can you please tell me the best way to set up the code?

I have tried this, within the called method function `getResults` that is in my class:

```
getResults() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (results){
        alert(results.title.rendered);
    }

    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/');
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

However that is giving me an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined"

I have been referencing this post that shows the JQuery and Plain JS versions of different things.  I need to use the plain JS. https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312

The results of the JSON request should be displayed on the page with a list of post titles. Though for the sake of this question I just want the titles to display in an `alert()`.

Comment: Can you log the result please ?

Comment: Conan, sorry, I am not sure what you are asking for, can you please clarify?

Comment: I'm asking if you can you replace `alert(results.title.rendered);` with `alert(results);` and send a screenshot ?

Comment: I changed the code to `alert(results);` and the alert displayed  [object Event]

Comment: I also just tried `alert(results.title);` and I got undefined in the alert

Answer (score 0):

Update your function like this :

```
function getResults() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         alert(obj.title);//if there is a title on your Json response
      }
    }

    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/');
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go, but that didn't work. It only displayed the raw JSON data, not the titles of the pages

Comment: @Iisrael try this last edit with json parser 'obj = JSON.parse();' this will parse your response into object... and thnx for up vote the answer...

Answer (score 0):

httpRequest.onreadystatechange has a property called readyState that is set every time the state of the request changes. You need to wait until readyState == 4 before your results object is populated.

Comment: So you can't use the XMLHttpRequest with out an IF statement?

Comment: you can, you just have to be able to catch the appropriate state. For example, you can use a switch statement. 

`switch(this.readyState) {
   case 4:
         console.log(this.responseText);
         break;
   case default:
        //do nothing
}`